# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^{m} n^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I would like to ask if anyone would help me to find a general formula for the sum of m members of the following series.
\begin{equation} 
      \sum_{n=1}^{m} n^n = 1^1+2^2+\cdots + m^m
\end{equation}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no known general formula for this sum.

Comment: Nice little rule of thumb: If [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001923) has your sequence, but doesn't have a closed expression for it, chances are there are no closed form expressions. Of course, absence of proof is not a proof of absence. Proving that it cannot be done (if it indeed cannot be done) is, presumably, **difficult**.

Comment: Note: in a 1946 article by F. Underwood, nice upper and lower bounds were given for this sum (see here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2306261)

Comment: Related on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/191216/the-hypertriangular-function-of-n